# Android login authentication not working

Tags: android, http

I have an application of login. When user fill up the form and click login button, then it takes a string from server and check, if correct, then go to the next activity. All are right but for first time it can not store the string. I think it is for background task. Value of the background task is the string. So the if condition depends on that string value. How can I get string before go to the next task.

Here is my activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button login;
EditText user, pass;
CheckBox ck;
String FILENAME = "check";
String checkenords;

String FILETOKEN = "token";
String tokenStr;

String responseStr;
String usernamefromuser;
int responsecode;
String passfromuser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_in);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

    login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        usernamefromuser = user.getText().toString();
        passfromuser = pass.getText().toString();

        Log.e("successss", "888888888888");
        Log.e("Username", "User:" + usernamefromuser);
        Log.e("Password", "pass:" + passfromuser);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String url = "http://54.228.149.123/api/auth";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        // httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> namevalpair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", passfromuser));
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",
                    usernamefromuser));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    namevalpair, HTTP.UTF_8);
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(httppost);
            responsecode = httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
            Log.d("Authentication", "" + responsecode);
            // Log.d("httpresponseeeee", httpresponse.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new CreateUser().execute();
    if (responsecode == 200) {
        tokenStr = responseStr;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILETOKEN,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(tokenStr.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (ck.isChecked()) {
            checkenords = "enable";
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(checkenords.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent inteGps = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Gps.class);
            startActivity(inteGps);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent inteGps = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Gps.class);
            startActivity(inteGps);
            finish();
        }
    } else if (responsecode == 401) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Username or Password",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
 }
```

But for first time, it show "Please try again", though responsecode=200 or responsecode=401. Please help me.

Comment: "It cannot store the string". But where? Where do you want to store it.

Comment: In the method onclick, I used a conditionthat if (responsecode == 200) {. So I need the string (responsecode). Before this condition. That is why I used "new CreateUser().execute();", this should save the value of "responsecode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Response validation should** be there in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask **not in onClick itself**, because if you keep it onclick it will immediately executed after   new CreateUser().execute(); i.e it never wait to get response from server.

Find the modified code,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new CreateUser().execute();
}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        usernamefromuser = user.getText().toString();
        passfromuser = pass.getText().toString();

        Log.e("successss", "888888888888");
        Log.e("Username", "User:" + usernamefromuser);
        Log.e("Password", "pass:" + passfromuser);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String url = "http://54.228.149.123/api/auth";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        // httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> namevalpair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", passfromuser));
            namevalpair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",
                    usernamefromuser));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    namevalpair, HTTP.UTF_8);
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(httppost);
            responsecode = httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
            Log.d("Authentication", "" + responsecode);
            // Log.d("httpresponseeeee", httpresponse.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

 @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       if (responsecode == 200) {
        tokenStr = responseStr;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILETOKEN,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(tokenStr.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (ck.isChecked()) {
            checkenords = "enable";
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(checkenords.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent inteGps = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Gps.class);
            startActivity(inteGps);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent inteGps = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Gps.class);
            startActivity(inteGps);
            finish();
        }
    } else if (responsecode == 401) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Username or Password",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you brother. Is there anyway to use toast in asynctask?

Comment: yeah you can show Toast (can update UI) using onProgressUpdate() method too, it used to show status update of background process. This method called whenever you publish progress in doInBackground() using onProgressUpdate() method. i.e it not wait to complete doInBackground.